# ASIFormDataRequest NULL response

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have simply form request in my Obj-c code, which calls a PHP code from my server

---

```
ASIFormDataRequest *req = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[req setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",slat] forKey:@"mylat"];
[req setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",slng] forKey:@"mylng"];
[req start];
NSLog(@"response -",[req responseString]);
[req release];
```

---

am not getting the response in the NSLog, but it runs very fine with stringWithContentsOfURL, and i can see the out put in the browser. even i changed the ASIFormDataRequest to ASIHTTPRequest and added User-Agent, but nothing works out. i checked it in different versions of SDKs also, 3.0, 3.1.2, 4.0, 4.1. but no response

I am sure the response from the server is fine,

one more sad thing is that, the same ASI code runs fine on my office network (AIRTEL Broadband) and not in my home which has a BSNL broadband, hope its not a service provider issue.

Did any one find such an issue..

Comment: Step through the code and dump the variables and add more information e.g. errors, values returned, etc

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
[req start]
```

Try:

```
[req startSynchronous]
```

Normally it is fine to manually call `-start` on an `NSOperation` object, but in this case, `ASIHTTPRequest` explicitly provides a `-startSynchronous` method, so there is probably a good reason to use it.

Comment: Finally i got the answer the Proxy is the problem, if you find the same issue, just check with the proxies in your network settings, i don know abt windows, am on MAC so its jus a chekbox to make it happen and the code i hv  used ( for safety purpose )

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
ASIFormDataRequest *req = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[req setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",slat] forKey:@"mylat"];
[req setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",slng] forKey:@"mylng"];

 [req startSynchronous];
  NSError *error = [req error];
  if (!error) {
      NSLog(@"response -",[req responseString]);
  }
[req release];
```

Comment: Thanks to Jordan & Josh, I will test it at home, but i don know how is it running in my office and the same is not running in home

Comment: am using the [req start] only here in office

Comment: I tried it, but its not working.... and now, its is also not working in my office network.. i don know why...

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer the Proxy is the problem, if you find the same issue, just check with the proxies in your network settings, i don know abt windows, am on MAC so its jus a chekbox to make it happen and the code i hv used ( for safety purpose )

```
ASIFormDataRequest *req = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[req setDelegate:self];
[req startAsynchronous];
NSError *error = [req error];
if (!error) {
    NSLog(@"response -",[req responseString]);
}
[req release];
[url release];
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
// Use when fetching text data
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"response %d-%@",[responseString length],responseString);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
NSError *error = [request error];
NSLog(@"error - %@\n",error);
}
```